# Unable to get substrings split properly for editing

Tags: java, substring

Before anyone panics, this is for a class, not a real company. The class requires the entire employee to be stored in a single string and for us to use substrings to split it up and edit each part. My issue is I cannot get my substrings split properly.

```
d[1] = edb[j].substring(0,25);//Last name (25 long)
d[2] = edb[j].substring(25,40);//First Name (15 long)
d[3] = edb[j].substring(40,41);//Middle Initial (1 long)
d[4] = edb[j].substring(41,52);//Social Security number (11 long)
d[5] = edb[j].substring(52,56);//Employee Number (4 long)
d[6] = edb[j].substring(56,68);//Phone Number (12 long)
d[7] = edb[j].substring(68,98);//Address 1 (30 long)
d[8] = edb[j].substring(98,128);//Address 2 (30 long)
d[9] = edb[j].substring(128,148);//City (20 long)
d[10] = edb[j].substring(148,150);//state abrev. (2 long)
d[11] = edb[j].substring(150,155);//zip code (5 long)
```

it will, for example, go Mazurkiewicz (next input) Joseph (next input) [blank] (next input) F xx-xxx-xxx. it will skip over the middle initial and put it at the begining of social leave out the last number of social security

Comment: The best advice I can come up with: Keep at it -- use your code, your data and your debugger to help you modify the code until it works.

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` liberally.  Print the whole string, the substrings, the indices and take note as to what is going on. It could also make your life easier if you assign things like `e[j]` to a simple String variable.  Then you don't need to keep typing in the index.

Comment: One more thing.  If you are counting fields based on spaces, it is possible that tabs could be used which can throw you off since they are just one character but appear to be several.

Comment: If the Middle Initial ends up in the Social Security number field, then the input is malformed, not conforming to the defined fixed-width column layout, *or* you misunderstood the format. Since we can't see the data, and we can't see the assignments definition of the format, it's difficult for us to help further, other than what already been suggested, i.e. debug/print values until it makes sense.

Comment: I just noticed that  you start assigning at `d[1]`.  Arrays in Java are 0-based.

Comment: The d[0] slot is where what the count is goes